# Are black holes related to the hole of the torus?

Tags: physics, general-relativity

I just read a little about [Euler characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Examples) of surfaces and now I wonder:

> Are black holes related to the hole of the [torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus)?

Since black holes are things in space-time and the torus' hole is something that is related to a surface, I'm not sure if the concept of Euler characteristics can be carried over to black holes. Can it?

To put it another way: What the Euler characteristic analogon of space-time with one black hole?

Comment: This seems kind of like a stretch. I honestly haven't a clue--I know nothing of physics--but you're argument seems to be that they are both spatially related holes. Yeah? Who knows though.

Comment: oh. Black holes, no; wormholes, yes.

Comment: not so many singularities on a torus...

Comment: @Alex *spatially related*, hmm, kind of. I mean, does our space-time then have a certain $\chi$ that is related to the number of black holes in the universe?

Comment: @Will, I agree, but some say that a wormhole is a black and (a) white hole. So you say that just having one doesn't change the topology of space-time? (and I hope that this a mathematically acceptable formulation...)

Comment: @james one could think of [Horn Torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Standard_torus-horn.png), but that's the way I would like to discuss this...

Comment: @draks... I would think the number of Black Holes in the universe would be the number of singularities in the spacetime manifold. In other words, it's an orbifold and the number of Black Holes is the finite number of singularities. But, I think this is probably quite naive given all the other ways gravity might break down (quantum)

Comment: Dear draks, A black hole is, at least *a priori*, a geometric phenomenon --- it is a certain kind of local solution to Eisenstein's equation on a $4$-dim'l Lorentzian manifold; one that gives rise to a singularity (i.e. makes the metric incomplete).  Euler characteristics and so on measure topological phenomena (although they can sometimes be computed geometrically, e.g. the Gauss--Bonnet formula).  But I don't think that the presence of singularities in space-time is directly related one way or another to its topology.  If you want to pursue your question in a serious way, you could look ...

Comment: ... at the book by Hawking and Ellis or the book of Penrose about relativity and differential geometry/topology.  Regards,

Comment: According to [Entropy and topology for manifolds with boundaries](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9509093.pdf#page=4) by Liberati and Pollifrone (page 4), In the Schwarzschild case one correctly obtains $\chi_\text{Euler} = 2$ which is the expected value for $S^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2$ topology.

Comment: @user76284 thanks and on page 5 they say "that for extreme black hole the Euler characteristic is always null", which is a circle, a torus, a Möbius band or a Klein bottle according to the [examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Examples)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm definitely not an expert, but here is my understanding. Mass (or energy) causes a change in the curvature tensor (not quite sure how this works). But the key is that this is a local property of the manifold. So imagine your torus is a ballon. Now poke the balloon. It will bend in, this changes the curvature close to where you push in. The amount that it curves is determined by how hard you push (which corresponds to the amount of mass) and the area over which you push in, this is how pressure works.

Now for a black hole, the mass is finite but the volume is 0, again this is all hypothetical, so this means that at the point of the mass the curvature is $\infty$, this is why it's called a singularity.

In the analogy of the balloon, it would be like pinching the balloon so that it is no longer smooth, but so that you get a "corner"

The key of all this is that it is essentially local and involves geometry.

Now if you talk about the hole of a torus, it is global and topological, not geometric. In fact a torus can be made to be as flat as a plane, locally at every point simultaneously (notice that this cannot be done for a sphere or a higher genus surface). So it is really of a different nature.

Now there was a comment about a wormhole. Well the idea there is that wormholes will change the topology of space-time to look like a torus, and there is a hypothesis that this can happen inside a black hole. But really this is jumping the gun, possibly to the point of being nonsensical. Before I get comments about my last statement, let me explain.

Because there is currently no physical theory that sufficiently explains what happens in a black hole, then in some sense there can be no wrong answers. So you can come up with all kinds of theories about what kinds of things can happen.

Comment: nice answer, the point that a torus is flat is probably an important one to make here.

Comment: @James: Yes, I will edit to emphasize this.

Comment: Coming to more earthly applications, a car tire is a torus, and you really don't want *that* to be flat! :)